# node-inspector blank screen on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I can't seem to get node-inspector to work on windows
I'm trying to debug this script:

app.js

```
console.log('HELLO WORLD');

debugger;

console.log('HELLO DEBUGGER');
setInterval(function () {
    debugger;
    console.log('HELLO');
}, 10000);
```

I tried following things, with and without elevated permissions:

```
node-debug app.js
//
node-inspector 
node --debug-brk app.js
```

In any event, 
If I navigate in chrome to `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`
I  just get a blank screen with an empty toolbar above and a grey toolbar below.

If I look into the devtools, it seems like chrome is waiting for the websocket to establish, the `ws://localhost:8080/ws?port=5858` keeps 'pending'

Versions:

```
Windows 7 Pro x64
node-inspector v0.7.3
node v0.10.26
chrome 33.0.1750.154 m
chrome 36.0.1930.0 canary
```

I'm running chrome with `--disable-extensions`

I can't seem to find any error logs, so I'm not sure where to go from here.
How I can fix / debug this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was the virus scanner.
I was using "Ad-Aware, Free Antivirus+", uninstalled it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When I read the answer above I realised it might be my AdBlock chrome plugin. I disabled it for localhost and it worked :)

Comment: Great ! Disabling your plugins should always be your first reaction.  ProTip™: you can create a separate chrome profile with no plugins to quickly test  these kind of issues. You can also use `--disable-extensions` flag but that requires you to restart chrome and is kind of a pain...

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was Motorola bloatware aka MotoHelperAgent.exe